# Using SUMIF correctly on google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-docs

I want a cell to give me the sums of the cells above, only when another column has values in it as well.  For instance, I want B5 to sum up B1:B4, only when C1:C4 also have values, if a C cell doesn't have a value, then I want the corresponding B cell to be counted as a 0 during the sum.  I looking up info on SumIf and FILTER but I don't know what to put in the criteria to make it accept any number, and how to report 0 when no number is available.  Any help would be appreciated.

---

What I tried doing so far:
=FILTER(B1:B4;C1:C4=value()   and I get an error

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have you tried using `SUMIF` like this:

```
=SUMIF(C1:C4, "<>", B1:B4)
```

?

It's working for me.

Comment: yes! thanks a lot. would you mind explaining to me what the "<>" does?

Comment: @user28790 You can click the tick outline to accept my answer :) The `<>` means not equal to and since there's nothing, it will mean 'not equal to blank'.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=SUMIF(C1:C4; "<>"; B1:B4)
```

or also, as Jerry suggested:

```
=SUMIF(C1:C4, "<>", B1:B4)
```

Note that the semi-colon separator is supported in all locales, so it is generally preferred.